# can constexpr function return type be a non const?

Tags: c++

I have read that `constexpr` function return type can be a non const and also in my book there is a code like this:

```
constexpr bool isShorter(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{
    return str1.size() < str2.size();
}
```

but there is an error under `str1.size()` that says: `constexpr`function return is non-const. According to the book it must be right but the compiler disagree.

Also every time I use `constexpr` in different codes there is always this error: **missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int**. But I don't know what it means.

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you know that `const` and `constexpr` are different?

Comment: And when is the return type const. Ps constexpr things are known at compile time

Comment: yes I know they are different

Comment: the main problem is that error every time I use constexpr (missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int).

Comment: The main problem is that this is crap code

Comment: @EdHeal `And when is the return type const.` I didn´t say that a const bool would be good, only that it is different.

Comment: It was meant to be a question

Comment: @saeedabbasi, Maybe you missed an include for `<string>`. It's hard to say without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including include directives, and possibly compiler information.

Comment: you treat as if you are expecting people to ask super professional  questions. remember that someone like me is alone in his room with just a book willing learn how to code and and is expecting  you to help.

Comment: @saeedabbasi `ask super professional questions` Yes, Stack Overflow wants that. Stack Overflow isn´t a site for all beginners to learn basics.

Comment: @chris no that would be a simple problem. that's some thing else

Comment: these things are not basic. I am at middle of my 1800 sheets c++ book

Comment: Maybe your other code isn't compiled with C++11, or with a compiler that has support for `constexpr`.

Comment: @chris I wrote a header for my function and the the error of 'str1.size()' went away but the compiler error is still there

Comment: @chrisI have the exactly version of compiler as my book has

Answer (score 5):

No, the return value must be a constant expression for at least one set of possible inputs.

N3797 §7.1.5 [dcl.constexpr]/5 says:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function or a
>   non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting constexpr constructor, if
>   no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or
>   constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant
>   expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Since `std::string::size` is not `constexpr`, there is no possible case where the return value is a constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` means the function returns a value that the compiler can determine before the program is run.

`const` just means the function, when called, does not change the object at run time.

The contents of a `std::string` are not fixed at compile time, so the `size()` method is `const` (e.g. calling it will not change a string containing data `"ABCD"` into `"ABCDEFG"`) but is not constexpr (the length of a `std::string` is not fixed at compile time, because the string can be populated at run time - such as based on user input).

This assumes compiling for C++11 or later - earlier versions of C++ do not support `constexpr`.