# A constexpr function is not required to return a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

**C++ Primer** (5th edition) on page 240 has a note stating:

> "A `constexpr` function is not required to return a constant expression".

A question has been asked about this: [can constexpr function return type be a non const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577778/can-constexpr-function-return-type-be-a-non-const). The author of that question misunderstood the note.

But what is the correct understanding of it (the answers to the cited post clarify the confusion of that post's author, but do not answer my question)?

Comment: Thank you Simon for formatting the question so nicely. I learned new things from this.

Comment: Scott Meyers explains this topic quite well in his new book, Effective Modern C++

Comment: @Alejandro What item number?

Comment: 15 for me, under "Moving to Modern C++"

Comment: You have two good answers below, do they answer your question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A (non-template) `constexpr` function must have at least one execution path that returns a constant expression; formally, there must exist argument values such that *"an invocation of the function [...] could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression"* (**[dcl.constexpr]**/5).  For example (ibid.):

```
constexpr int f(bool b) { return b ? throw 0 : 0; }     // OK
constexpr int f() { return f(true); }     // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

Here `int f(bool)` is allowed to be `constexpr` because its invocation with argument value `false` returns a constant expression.

It is possible to have a `constexpr` function that cannot ever return a constant expression if it is a specialization of a function template that could have at least one specialization that does return a constant expression.  Again, with the above:

```
template<bool B> constexpr int g() { return f(B); }    // OK
constexpr int h() { return g<true>(); }    // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
```

Comment: What is the usefulness in declaring `g<true>()` as `constexpr`? Can you write `constexpr int a = g<true>();`? I guess not, because the compiler will not be able to compute the initialization value for `a` at compile time...

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg correct, but you can write `constexpr int a = g<false>();`, so the Standard allows `g()` to be `constexpr`.

Comment: Ah right, it won't compile if I omit `constexpr` in the specialization! Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean to do an explicit instantiation of `g<true>()` or an explicit specialization? And why is `h()` ill-formed NDR exactly?

Comment: @T.C. that's an explicit instantiation (an explicit specialization that would not be `constexpr`-valid is ill-formed NDR per paragraph 6). Sorry for any confusion on `h()` - I forgot the `constexpr` specifier. Without `constexpr` it would be well-formed, as you've observed.

Comment: Then you don't want the `<>`...? `template<>` would be an explicit specialization.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, I've removed that line as it wasn't really clarifying things.

Answer (score 15):

A `constexpr` function <s>must return</s>* must have a path that returns a constant expression iff all parameters are constant expressions. This actually makes sense. Example:

```
constexpr int square(int i){
    return i*i;
}

std::array<int, square(2)> ia; //works as intended, constant expression
int i;
std::cin >> i;
int j = square(i); //works even though i is not a constant expression
std::array<int, square(i)> ia; //fails, because square does not (and cannot)
                               //return a constant expression
```

*Correction by [chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/962089/chris).

Comment: I disagree. As long as it's possible for the function to return a constant expression, it's okay. It's allowed to take a constant expression parameter and return a non-constant expression as long as it returns a constant expression another time (e.g., http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d9dcadc756749c). This argument is taken from the question the OP linked to.

Comment: Within the constexpr function, the parameters are not considered as constant expressions. Hence, even `constexpr int foo(int i) { return i; }` does not *return a constant expression*. The wording in C++ Primer is a bit silly IMHO. What the Standard requires is that one must be able to call a constexpr function inside a constant expression (there exist arguments such that the function can be called inside a constant expression).